# How to use NTFS-3G installed using MacPort?

Tags: mac, osx-lion, macports, ntfs-3g, macfuse

After upgrading to Lion I'm having problem mounting NTFS drives in read/write mode. This is because NTFS-3G distributed by http://www.tuxera.com does not work with Lion.

As far their suggestion I installed NTFS-3G using MacPort. But as far as I can see it does not come with the usual preference pane. Its not enabled by default.

Do anyone know how to enable it? Or how to have the Preference Pane for the NTFS-3G from MacPorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already found it, there is a tutorial at:

http://fernandoff.posterous.com/ntfs-write-support-on-osx-lion-with-ntfs-3g-f

He describes two ways to use ntfs-3g with lion, one of which uses macports.